# how to modify python's built in modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, built-in

I want to add functions to python's built in module. As a example, there is no  find function in list. I want to add it. There is some other functions I want to add. Can somebody please tell me how can I do that? Is their any way I can do that?

Comment: You generally don't try to monkey patch anything in Python, that introduces invisible dependencies.

Comment: BTW, there is a `find` function in `list`. It's called [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: It'd probably be best to not do this, and just use the functions as plain functions, not methods. Have you already considered that?

Comment: In the spirit of @Elazar 's comment, it is advisable that you learn to use fundamental Python objects like `list` properly before you decide they are unsatisfactory and need to be fixed or extended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding functions to the builtins module is simple:

```
import builtins
builtins.find = my_find_function
```

But the built in classes are usually immutable, so they cannot be changed.

```json
>>> list.hello = "hello"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'list'
```